# How would I find the PDF of one poisson variable in terms of another?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, queueing-theory

I am looking for the PDF of a Poisson variable.

The setup is that pit crews are working on racecars on the track after the drivers reports trouble. The pit crew's expected work time is exponentially distributed with an expected value of $\frac 1{\lambda}$. The drivers arrive as a Poisson process with rate $\mu$

So far I have tried using a convolution integral to get the PDF of the wait. I set up the PDF of the arrival as $\mu e^{-\mu t}$ and the PDF of the expected work time as $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$. Then I took the convolution as follows.

$P_W(t) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \mu e^{-\mu\tau}\lambda e^{-\lambda (t-\tau)}d \tau$

I got $-\frac{\mu\lambda }{\mu-\lambda }e^{(\lambda-\mu)\tau- \lambda t)}|^{\tau \to\infty}_{\tau \to-\infty}$ which seems to diverge.

Am I completely on the wrong track or am I missing something?

Comment: Achtung: the pdf of a Poisson random variable is supported on $\mathbb{R}^+$. This is the reason for your integral to diverge!

Comment: What happens if a second driver arrives before work on the first has finished? And what precisely are you trying to get a distribution for?

Comment: @Henry I am trying to get the distribution for the wait time. I need to find the probability that the 2nd car will have to wait and their expected wait time

Comment: It would also diverge if $\lambda > \tau$ which does not make sense to me either.

Comment: The important part is that probability and expected value. If there is a better way to get to it than I'll accept an answer putting me on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read about an [M/M/1 queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue), though I think Wikipedia has your $\lambda$ and $\mu$ reversed.

The probability that any one time there are $N$ cars being serviced or waiting is  $\left(\frac{\mu}{\lambda}\right)^N\left(1-\frac{\mu}{\lambda}\right)$ so when a new car arrives, the expected number of cars in front is $\frac{\mu}{\lambda-\mu}$ and the expected waiting time until its service starts is  $\frac{\mu}{\lambda(\lambda-\mu)}$ while the expected waiting time until its service finishes is  $\frac{1}{\lambda-\mu}$.

The queue is unstable, with infinite expected waiting times, if $\mu \ge \lambda$.

Comment: This is a great answer, took a route I didn't consider either. We have covered Markov chains, I think the expectation is to use the distribution of Poisson processes. But I have a sanity check because I know what I should get now.